# Pagination after reindex in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am new in Azure Search Service and I am not sure I got one important thing about it:

Let's pretend the situation when I am as a client scrolling down through results of my search query:

*"New Y"*. I have 1000 elements, every page contains 10 of it. But during my scroll reindex operation has been started and some elements changed their position concerning new updates in data source (Azure Table).

Will I see next pages during my scrolling after reindex with probably some duplicated data or it still be the old "snapshot" of data I was scrolling before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see the changes as you execute subsequent requests. To Azure Search each request is independent and it represents a new search (caching aside), which for paging scenarios just happens to have a different "skip" number.

This means that if your data is changing you might see an item more than once (if it moves across pages due to changes) or even skip one (if it moves from a page you didn't see yet to a page you already saw).

There's no way to get a strictly consistent view of search matches outside of a single result. If you need to approximate this behavior you can request a larger page (using "top"), cache the results and present them in chunks. We find that in practice this is rarely needed for most search scenarios, but if search is backing a part of an app that needs consistency you might need to something along those lines.

Comment: It seems like a bad Web API design. I mean paging data with $top/$skip parameters will always cause issues with duplicated items. The cursor-based pagination solves such problem. Here is a good article about that http://vermorel.com/journal/2015/5/8/nearly-all-web-apis-get-paging-wrong.html. I wonder why Azure Search still doesn't provide any reliable way for "paging".